# Preposition in "von dort kommen"

Tags: preposition

From an interview in *Die Zeit*

> "Ich werde in den Niederlanden studieren, von dort kommen meine Eltern."

Usually we would use "aus" (and not "von") in

> Ich komme aus den Niederlanden.
>
> **NOT**: Ich komme von den Niederlanden.

So, is it correct to use "von" (and not "aus") in

> Meine Eltern kommen von dort.

? Is the change of preposition due to "dort"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, is it correct to use "von" (and not "aus") in

yes it is

> Is the change of preposition due to "dort"?

that's the point. Changing from "Niederlande" to "dort" changes the preposition from "aus" to "von".